# Doctrine Annontiation OneToOne,ManyToOne etc do not work in symfony

Tags: symfony, orm, annotations

This is very strange for me.
I am working with symfony 3 and trying to create 2 tables with 2 different entities. Both shouls be linked with ManyToOne. After clearing the cache und updating doctrine, both fields are not linked together.

So I did an easy OneToOne with 2 similar Entities

User:

```
'/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="md_user")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
*/


 class User
{
/**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type = "integer")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Userdata")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userdata_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $cid;'
```

Userdata:

```
    '/**
     * MdUser
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="md_userdata")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserdataRepository")



     */
    class  Userdata
    {
/**
* @var id
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="cid")
*/
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=255)
         */
        protected $last_name;
'
```

After Updating Doctrine in symfony nothing changed. Can somebody tell me, what am I doing wrong ?

Added config.yml:

```
'imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: de

framework:
    cache:
        pools:
            app.cache.doctrine_orm:
                adapter: cache.system
    esi: ~
    translator:
       fallbacks: ['%locale%']
       paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/app/Resources/translations']

    session:
        handler_id: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler

    secret: '%secret%'
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing.yml'
        strict_requirements: ~
    form: ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:
         enable_annotations: true
         enabled: true
    #serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    trusted_hosts: ~

    fragments: ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
#       base_path: ./../Resources/views/Frontend/

    php_errors:
        log: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
#    globals:
#        fos_csrf_provider: "@form.csrf_provider"

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"

knp_menu:
    #  if true, enables the helper for PHP templates
    templating: true
    # the renderer to use, list is also available by default
    default_renderer: twig
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        metadata_cache_driver:
                   type: service
                   id: app.doctrine_orm.cache
        result_cache_driver:
                   type: service
                   id: app.doctrine_orm.cache
        query_cache_driver:
                   type: service
                   id: app.doctrine_orm.cache
        second_level_cache:
                    enabled: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }
# ...
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'

    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~

'
```

services.yml

```
'# Learn more about services, parameters and containers at
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html
parameters:
    #parameter_name: value

services:

    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler:
        public:    false
        arguments:
            - 'mysql:host=%database_host%;port=%database_port%;dbname=%database_name%'
            - { db_table: md_sessions, db_username: '%database_user%', db_password: '%database_password%' }


    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        # automatically injects dependencies in your services
        autowire: true
        # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        autoconfigure: true
        # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
        # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
        public: false

    # makes classes in src/AppBundle available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        # you can exclude directories or files
        # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure they're public
    # and have a tag that allows actions to type-hint services
    AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']


    app.session_handler:
       class: 'AppBundle\EventListener\MandantListener'
       arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
       tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request }

    app.template_listener:
        class: 'AppBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener'
        arguments: ["@twig"]
        tags:
         - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }

    app.doctrine_orm.cache:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\DoctrineProvider
        arguments: ["@app.cache.doctrine_orm"]

    app.locale_listener:
       class: 'AppBundle\EventListener\LocaleSubscriber'
       arguments: ["%kernel.default_locale%"]
       tags: [kernel.event_subscriber]
'
```

Comment: Verify that Resources/config/doctrine does not have any old mapping files.

Comment: Thx. I will check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a conflicting declaration : a column cannot be auto-generated AND a relation to another entity at the same time.

So change your `UserData`'s `$id` to reflect that : remove the auto generation, something along those lines :

```
class  Userdata
{
    /**
    * @var id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="cid")
    */
    protected $id;
}
```

... but it's not really a good practice, since you need a unique ID anyway. **So I would go a different route and create a new field to hold that specific relation.** The original ID is left auto-generated, and you create a new field for the relation with `cid`.

*PS : As well, you declare the `@ORM\Entity` twice on `User`. Not a big deal, but so you know*

Comment: Thx. So many mistakes :-((
The original id in Userdata is automatically the CustomerID. So I can keep it. But it should not be AUTO generated.

Comment: I got it. Thx for help